# jQuery disabling anchor links

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery Tab Code:

```
$(function() {  
  $('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide divs
  $('#tabs div:first').show(); // Show first div
  $("li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var currentTab = $(this.children).attr('href'); // Set currentTab to value of href attribute
    $('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide all divs
    $(currentTab).show(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
    return false;
  });
});
```

The thing is, that each time I click on an anchor links it "toggles" a tab:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="tabrow">
  <li class="selected"><a href="#tab-one">Contest</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-two">Prizes</a></li>


</ul>

<div id="tab-one" class="center">
</div>
<div id="tab-two" class="center">
</div>
</div>
```

How can I do so only the links in the UL will be affected by this jQuery code?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HyNfJ/4/ because from the Fiddle, I'm not sure what the issue/problem is :z

Comment: Since your code works fine just make your selection to li more specific like $("#tabrow li").click(....) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...
 $('a.something').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

It will disable the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$("li").click(
```

to

```
$(".tabrow a").click(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.tabrow li a').click(function(e) {
    var $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.removeClass('selected');
    // etc...
});
```

Your jQuery selector is not specific enough. You need to target the anchor tag for the click event, or use `.delegate` instead of `.click` (`.bind`).